# Use jSON data in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I've got a json list like this in Angular:

```
vm.allnews = actualNews;
```

I checked it on console.log and it works. Getting all news by array list.
Every list has title and I can shot it on Angular template:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="news in newsPage.allnews">

    {{news.title}}

..
```

And it works too. But I have a form and must be send news title in data and I tried like that:

```
 function sendTitle () {
var title = $scope.news.title;
..
```

But its getting '`title undefined'` error.
Whats the problem? How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have `$scope.news` but `$scope.newsPage.allnews`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a parameter with relevant object from array.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="news in newsPage.allnews">
   <div>{{news.title}}</div>
   <div ng-click="sendTitle(news.title)">Submit</div>
</div>
```